# Why is Django is looking at wrong urls file?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am using Django 2.2 version.

In my `settings.py` I have the below setting:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'project12.urls'
```

When I try to open a page I get the following warning.

```
Using the URLconf defined in project1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
The current path, testnow, didn't match any of these.
```

As you can see, settings is`project12.urls` but it is looking for `project1.urls`.
I changed the `settings.py` several times, but it is still looking for `project1.urls`.

Comment: have you restarted the django server?

Comment: You were right. Thanks alot. I was inattentive. I ran "sudo systemctl enable uwsgi" several times in spite of "sudo systemctl restart uwsgi". Now restarted services and working.

Comment: cool, leaving an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the server should do the trick